# What's the correct way to assign an element by index to a knockout.js observableArray?

Tags: knockout.js, ko.observablearray

I've been looking at the [documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observableArrays.html) for knockout's `observableArray`, and I'm having trouble figuring out how to do one of the most fundamental things you can do with an array:  assign a value by index.

Things I've tried: (given `oa = ko.observableArray([1,2,3])`)

- `oa(1, 10);`
- `oa[1] = 10;`
- `oa()[1] = 10;`
- `oa.splice(1, 1, 10);`

The last one seems work, but I'm concerned that `.splice()` might be inefficient since it has to be concerned with shifting all the subsequent values.  I'd prefer to just do simple index-based assignment.

I've [created a jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4yGPh/) that shows an observableArray being weird.

```
<ol data-bind="foreach: list">
    <li data-bind="text: $data"></li>
</ol>

<script>
    var model = {
        list: ko.observableArray([3, 5, 7])
    };

    ko.applyBindings(model);

    setTimeout(function() {
        model.list()[1] = 55;
        model.list.push(99);
        model.list()[2] = 77;
    }, 2000);
</script>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apply *valueHasMutated* property on your observable after modification

```
setTimeout(function() {
    model.list()[1] = 55;
    model.list.push(99);
    model.list()[2] = 77;
    model.list.valueHasMutated();
}, 2000);
```

Answer (score 3):

Observable array notifies its listeners of changes (and thus causes corresponding views update) when mutating method is called or it is initialized with a new array.

```
oa()[i] = x;
oa(oa());
```

You can factor this out into an extension method:

```
ko.observableArray.fn.setItem = function(index, newValue) {
    var items = this();
    items[index] = newValue;
    this(items);
};
```

`foreach` binding is smart enough to detect that only one element is changed and there is no need to render other nodes again.

Answer (score 1):

The way you assigned values in your fiddle works fine. If you do a `console.log()` of your model.list() object, you can actually see that the values of the array are updated correctly.

The key thing to remember is the following bit in the documentation:

> Key point: An observableArray tracks which objects are in the array, not the state of those objects
>
> Simply putting an object into an observableArray doesn’t make all of that object’s properties themselves observable. Of course, you can make those properties observable if you wish, but that’s an independent choice. An observableArray just tracks which objects it holds, and notifies listeners when objects are added or removed.

This is the reason your view isn't being updated with the new value in index 2, because it's not an observable value. Something (quick and dirty) like this will work:

```
var model = {
    list: ko.observableArray([ko.observable(3), ko.observable(5), ko.observable(7)])
};
model.list()[2](77); // Yeah, looks weird.
```

Comment: "An observableArray tracks which objects are in the array, not the state of those objects".  This is exactly why I'd expect there to be some mechanism to replace an object in the array with another object, and ko would be aware of it.  My example doesn't show me changing the property of an object in an array, but rather replacing the entire object.  It is an important distiction though, you are right.